# NoSuchMethodError for certain devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, android-dialogfragment, nosuchmethoderror

I have an Android app which includes a dialog fragment that has 4 selections, each leading to an Alert Dialog with additional information On Click.

This functionality is working for my device (Galaxy S7 Edge, Android 7.0), but I am getting reports from users saying their app is crashing when they click a selection (should open the alert dialog).

My diagnostics say that the error is caused by a NoSuchMethodError for the OnClick, only occurring in Android versions 4.4, 5.0, 5.1 (as of now).

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue? It's very hard to troubleshoot since it works on my device.

Thanks!

NOTE: I am using View.OnClickListener if that changes anything.

Error stack trace example:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  at com.myname.builder.Page$6.onClick(Page.java:98)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4459)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18443)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5128)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
```

And here is the fragment with the error:

```
public class Page extends DialogFragment {

    private View view;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private String name
    private Object object;

    static class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView a1;
        private TextView a1t;
        private Button close;
        private RelativeLayout a1c;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kit_page, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.a1c = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(...);

            holder.a1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(...);

            holder.a1t = (TextView) view.findViewById(...);

            holder.close = (Button) view.findViewById(...);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        name = getArguments().getString("name", "N/A");

        object = getByName(name);

        holder.a1t.setText(god.getAb1().getName());
        holder.a1.setImageResource(getDrawableByName(1, god.getString()));


        holder.close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        holder.a1c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog dialog;
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ability_page, null);

        (...)

                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();

                Button dismiss = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);

                dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Pass a container in this View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ability_page, null);
.. It can be because your alertview doesn't have a rootView.

Comment: @TerrilThomas Sorry if this seems obvious, but are you referring to the second parameter in the .inflate( ) function? I'm relatively new to Android development

Comment: Yes. It is the second paramter or simply don't use the getRootView()

Comment: @TerrilThomas Makes sense! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ability_page, null); //Replace null with the Container 

        (...)
//or
                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext()); // Simply pass the Page.this here
                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you! Spent way too much time trying to figure this out